# Android Studio: Error while pinging URL: http://google.com. Cleartext HTTP traffic to google.com not permitted

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, admob, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

I am testing `Facebook Audience Network` ads with `AdMob` `mediation`. I am testing it using `Mediation Test Suite` as mentioned in their documentation.

I get this error when I try to load an ad from facebook ads in the Mediation Test Suite (Loading an ad from admob works fine).

```
Error while pinging URL: http://google.com. Cleartext HTTP traffic to google.com not permitted
Ad failed to load : 0
```

There's a lot of similar questions asked here in SO but none of them are working for me.
This has something to do with the `Network security configuration`. According their documentation I have added all the necessary files in my app. Here are they:

`res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    ...
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
    ...
</application>
```

I have also tried using `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` inside manifest file but then I get this error:

```
Ad failed to load : 0
Received non-success response code 302 from pinging URL: http://google.com
```

I have uninstalled and installed my app as suggested in some of the answers on SO but still not working.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I also want to know what is the use of adding Network security configuration. I use admob without Network security configuration has no problem. But developer guide say that the app will be more secure. The question is I don't know if adding will affect GDPR consent SDK or privacy website access or go to Google Play for comments or rating or Admob finding ads unit.

Comment: @Junior I currently face the same issue, have you found the reason behind it? or the solution to it?